# Slow faucet when water gets hot and does not resume flow

Tags: plumbing, faucet, kitchen-sink

I have a problem with my kitchen faucet:

- If the pipes have cooled off, it runs as fast as the cold side.
- As the pipes warm up, and warm water starts flowing, it slows down.
- As long as the water is warm/hot, it flows slowly.

This is the same as [this issue](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/134012/slow-faucet-when-water-gets-hot) except my flow never clears up until I turn the faucet off and wait for some time. I can also pinpoint the start of this issue: I replaced the cartridge (the original was marked N35DW, apparently a standard cartridge for single-handle faucets) with the only one the local store had that fit (Danco 89902, if it matters) and this caused the flow issue.

My question is, should I get a cartridge from another manufacturer and try that, or is there something else I should check first? The cartridges are $15-20 each so I'm a little hesitant to just go out and try another without another set of eyes on the problem.

Comment: Does this happen with all faucets and tubs/showers? If you have an instant hot water water heater then it could be overwhelmed with unusually cold ground water or starting to fail.

Comment: Nope. it only happens with this one. And it didn't start happening until I replaced the cartridge.

Comment: Have you thrown away the original cartridge? What was wrong with it? Can you install the old one and see if the problem persists? A proper replacement seems to be about $10 https://www.amazon.com/IAPMO-Certified-Replacement-Faucet-Cartridge/dp/B00SL64VAA so I would recommend trying that. If not then make sure you read all the instruction carefully for your new cartridge. Try taking it out and re-installing with from scratch.

Comment: Reinstalling the original cartridge to see if the problem persists is a good idea. I still have the cartridge but tossed the gasket like a dummy, hopefully the one from the replacement fits.

Edit: And to answer your question, the original cart leaked, both out of the faucet and through the valve itself. It works well enough for this test though.

Comment: For the record, the problem went away without further intervention. It cleared up in a couple weeks.